# HttpWebResponse and Int

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I am integrating with a REST service and so far so good.
Hit a little bit of a hurdle.
I am hitting the service via a HttpWebRequest.
I am receiving responses successfully, but in running the HttpWebResponse GetResponseStream through a StreamReader, i am getting back an

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">427</int>.
```

A little stuck on how to convert this back to a c# int.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to convert the string "427" to an integer? Or is that the status code of the page you're requesting?

Comment: ahhh sorry just realise the response got stripped from my post.  See below.  Getting back an XSD int.

Comment: <int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">427</int>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) and [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) methods in conjunction with a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) which you could use to load the response XML into:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(...);
...
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetStream())
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    if (int.TryParse(doc.Root.Value, out value))
    {

        // the parsing was successful => you could do something with
        // the integer value you have just read from the body of the response
        // assuming the server returned the XML you have shown in your question,
        // value should equal 427 here.
    }
}
```

or even easier, the Load method of XDocument understands HTTP, so you could even do this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://foo/bar");
if (int.TryParse(doc.Root.Value, out value))
{
    // the parsing was successful => you could do something with
    // the integer value you have just read from the body of the response
    // assuming the server returned the XML you have shown in your question,
    // value should equal 427 here.
}
```

this way you don't even need to use any HTTP requests/responses. Everything will be handled for you by the BCL which is kinda great.

Comment: @Franky, see what? I don't see anything. Have you updated your post or something? The comment you have posted to your question is useless. Completely unreadable. If you want to show some XML please update your original question and format it properly.

Comment: Darren - not too sure - didn't realise i could edit the original... instead i added it into the comment... Thanks for updating it.

Comment: @Franky, OK, now that your question is properly formatted I have updated my answer to take into account the XML that you have.

Comment: @Darren - unfortunately, if i pass the stream into the Load() method, i receive 'root elemeent is missing error', if i pass the stream.ReadToEnd into the Load(), i receive 'Illegal characters in path.' error.

Comment: @Franky, then you have not shown us the exact response that the server sends. You should not pass `stream.ReadToEnd()` to the Load method. You should just pass the response stream. But of course if the server didn't send valid XML (which is what we all thought it was sending according to your question), then you will have to show us what exactly the server is sending. You cannot just feed anything to a XDocument. It must be XML.

Comment: the exact response is that in the orginal post that you fixed for me.  That is the full XML response i am receiving.

Comment: @Franky, ah, then this should work without any problem. Alternatively try like this: `XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd())`.

Comment: you are 100% correct, slighty typo on my part - XDocument.Load was outside my using closing bracket!  Stupid mistake.  Working now.... THANK YOU VERY MUCH! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to convert the string "427" to an `int` then use the `Int32.Parse` method.

```
var str = "427";
var number = Int32.Parse(str);  // value == 427
```